# Is it possible to control my Android/iOS with Actions on Google?

Tags: google-api, actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I wonder if it's possible to control or interact with my installed app from Actions on Google. From the documentation [Extending the Google Assistant.](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant)  I don't see any possibilities to interact with the app. It seems to be a pure Google Assistant integration.
Has anyone else other experiences?

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google provides some ability to interact with an Android app. If you associate your Action with an app in the Play Store by using the console then your action can call `askToDeepLink()`. If the user consents, the rest of the interaction with a user can be carried out on the phone.

If your app is associated with your domain on the web then you can also use a "**link-out**" suggestion chip which when tapped will open an Android app. You can also put a button on a basic card which will do the same thing.

There is another older technology that integrates Google Now and Android described here  [Google Now Actions: Search Actions For Android Apps](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-now-actions-19436.html)  among other places.